# Http request for js and css file

Tags: javascript, css, httpwebrequest

In my website, when I analysed it. Shows that my site has a 17 external js file and 4 css file. And recommended me to reduce the number of http request made.

And my questions are...

> 1) Does more http requests reduce
>   overall ranking?
>
> 2) If I reduce my http requests by
>   combining js file, the js and css file
>   will be larger. Is it possible to
>   reduce the size too?
>
> Please give me some solutions.

Comment: Try this, download 20 files of 10kb and download 1 file of 250kb. Which one was faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by combining js and css files into one you will reduce number of requests made, you will be saving on time that way. you cannot reduce size to zero, try compressing your js and css files using [YUI COmpresssor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)

Answer (score 5):

The suggestion to reduce the number of http requests is valid. Speed will suffer generally because many browsers will only download two files from the same domain at a time, and since Google has announced that speed does now effect their rankings it is wise to address the issue. You can combine your js and css files, use a compression like gzip on the server to reduce their size or even ["compress"](http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/main/csscompressor) them using a number of free tools online.